# How can i make the ball in pong slower?

Tags: python, pong

ball then moves way too quick

```
    #Move the ball 
    ball.setx(ball.xcor() + ball.dx)
    ball.sety(ball.ycor() + ball.dy)
```

Comment: - your question is vage. Post more code or at least where you declared and assigned values to the used variables.
- Use Pastebin for code, explain code and what happens, actions etc....
- always include information about platforms you are testing, writing the code on.
- indicate language, framework, IDE, OS type (Windows, Linux, MacOS or mobile device etc...)
- make sure we can reproduce so add steps how to
Writing more complete questions will speed up the process of getting good and relevant answers and solutions instead of endless questions after questions cause of lack of information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ball.setx(ball.xcor() + (ball.dx / 2))
ball.sety(ball.ycor() + (ball.dy / 2))
```

50% speed

Answer (score 0):

The ball is moving based upon the values in `ball.dx` and `ball.dy`. If you edit these values to be less, the ball will move a lesser distance each loop, and therefore appear to move more slowly.

Try making a large change in value to see the effect obviously.